# Not getting result using ajax on wordpress

Tags: plugins, jquery, ajax, woocommerce-offtopic

I have used the following code on my functions.php page

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'my_ajax_button');

function my_ajax_button() {
echo '<button class="buy-this-room myajax" id="buy_this_room" >Buy This Room</button> 
      <button class="buy-this-design myajax" id="buy_this_design" >Buy This Design</button>';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'my_action_javascript');

function my_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var ajaxurl = "<?php admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
$('.myajax').click(function(){
    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        whatever: 1234
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});


});
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

 function my_action_callback() {
 global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

 $whatever = $_POST['whatever'];

 $whatever += 10;

         echo $whatever;

 exit(); // this is required to return a proper result & exit is faster than 

}
```

Ajax call is happening but i'm not getting the result.Alert is showing like this

```
Got this from the server: <!DOCTYPE html>
 <!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie ie9" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
 <html  lang="en-US">
 <head>
```

Can anybody help please!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its looks like you are not printing the admin ajax URL.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_action_javascript');

function my_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
$('.myajax').click(function(){
    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        whatever: 1234
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});


});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Please see that am printing the admin url using echo. Since there is no URL in ajax call you are getting the whole page.

Additional Info: For non logged in user, use `wp_ajax_nopriv`

Comment: My Pleasure. Many times this happens :)